# I want to compute the mean for each subject id with different lengths and using a start year and end year in R

Tags: r

I have dataset and for each observation there is a start year and end year. The dataset has being populated for all the years (2003 to 2011). And these years are variables/columns of their own and so for each observation, I just to keep the data that correspond to both the start year and end year.
For example if

| Id | Start Yr | End yr | Y2003 | Y2004 | Y2005 | Y2006 | Y2007 | Y2008 | Y2009 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| T001 | 2003 | 2007 | 2.3 | 1.1 | 1.2 | 1.8 | 7.2 | 5.6 | 10.2 |
| T002 | 2006 | 2007 | 3.0 | 3.9 | 2.2 | 2.7 | 5.4 | 4.5 | 3.9 |

so subject with id T001, I want to only take the values in year 2003 to year 2007 and compute the mean. So I want to have

| Id | Start Yr | End yr | Y2003 | Y2004 | Y2005 | Y2006 | Y2007 | Y2008 | Y2009 | Mean |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| T001 | 2003 | 2007 | 2.3 | 1.1 | 1.2 | 1.8 | 7.2 |  |  |  |
| T002 | 2006 | 2007 |  |  |  | 2.7 | 5.4 |  |  |  |

For id T001, the mean will be 2.72 and for T002 , the mean will be 4.05.
Thank you. I'm new to R

Answer (score 1):

You could use `rowwise()` and `c_across()` to get the job done.

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <- tribble(
  ~Id,  ~"Start Yr",    ~"End yr",  ~Y2003,     ~Y2004,     ~Y2005,     ~Y2006,     ~Y2007, ~Y2008, ~Y2009,
  "T001",   2003,   2007,   2.3,    1.1,    1.2,    1.8,    7.2,    5.6,    10.2,
  "T002",   2006,   2007,   3.0,    3.9,    2.2,    2.7,    5.4,    4.5,    3.9,
)


df %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(Mean = mean(c_across(
    cols = ends_with(as.character(`Start Yr`)):ends_with(as.character(`End yr`))
  )))
#> # A tibble: 2 × 11
#> # Rowwise: 
#>   Id    `Start Yr` `End yr` Y2003 Y2004 Y2005 Y2006 Y2007 Y2008 Y2009  Mean
#>   <chr>      <dbl>    <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1 T001        2003     2007   2.3   1.1   1.2   1.8   7.2   5.6  10.2  2.72
#> 2 T002        2006     2007   3     3.9   2.2   2.7   5.4   4.5   3.9  4.05
```

But they require the use of the `dplyr` package.

Answer (score 0):

A `tidyverse` approach to achieve your desired result may look like so:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  pivot_longer(-c(Id, Start.Yr, End.yr), names_prefix = "Y", names_transform = as.integer) %>%
  mutate(value = if_else(name >= Start.Yr & name <= End.yr, value, NA_real_)) %>%
  group_by(Id) %>%
  mutate(Mean = mean(value, na.rm = TRUE)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = name, values_from = value, names_prefix = "Y") %>%
  relocate(Mean, .after = last_col())
#> # A tibble: 2 × 11
#>   Id    Start.Yr End.yr Y2003 Y2004 Y2005 Y2006 Y2007 Y2008 Y2009  Mean
#>   <chr>    <int>  <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1 T001      2003   2007   2.3   1.1   1.2   1.8   7.2    NA    NA  2.72
#> 2 T002      2006   2007  NA    NA    NA     2.7   5.4    NA    NA  4.05
```

**DATA**

```
df <- structure(list(Id = c("T001", "T002"), Start.Yr = c(2003L, 2006L), End.yr = c(2007L, 2007L), Y2003 = c(2.3, 3), Y2004 = c(
  1.1,
  3.9
), Y2005 = c(1.2, 2.2), Y2006 = c(1.8, 2.7), Y2007 = c(
  7.2,
  5.4
), Y2008 = c(5.6, 4.5), Y2009 = c(10.2, 3.9)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(
  NA,
  -2L
))
``
```